# Execute macro when Word template is attached

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to run some code when I attach a template to a Word document.

I tried the `Document_Open` and `Document_New` methods to no avail.

I also tried the `AutoNew` and `AutoOpen` method from [this article](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DocumentEvents.htm).
The AutoOpen method is triggered when I attach my template to the document, close it, and then open the document again.

How can I trigger a line of code to execute when I attach the template to a document?

---

**EDIT :**
Currently we are attaching the template through the `Templates` dialog.

We are also adding a button in the ribbon, with the below code, to attach the template.

```
savedTmplt = "C:\Program Files\*****\template.dotm"

Set q = wd.ActiveDocument    
wd.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros False

With q
    .AttachedTemplate = savedTmplt
    .UpdateStyles
End With

wd.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
```

Comment: How are you attaching the template.  Progrmatically from within VBA or by theFile.Option.Addin.Templates dialog

Comment: @Freeflow I have added the details in the question.

Comment: You need to investigate the application.run method. This will run a macro in the newly attached template without causing a compilation error due to the non availability of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there is an Open event and a New event there is’nt an AttachTemplate event. So it simply isn’t possible to have code automatically respond to the template being attached.

Your options are:

- Attach the template then close and reopen the document.
- Attach the template then explicitly call the routine you want to run.